# Guardar data e hora do inicio da tarefa com botão e inseirir em mysql

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho o seguinte formulário que insere corretamente na base de dados ao clicar no botão:

```js
$("#form").submit(function(e){ 
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "./conexaoteste",
      data: $("#form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (data)
           {   
             
           }, 
          error: function(data){
      $(".error_message").removeClass('hide'); // error message
           },
     
   });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" id="form"> 
<input type="hidden" id="codigo" name="codigo" value="<?= $_GET['codigo'] ?>" />
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="PequenoAlmoco" id="acao"></label>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="hidden" id="PequenoAlmoco" name="tarefa" value="Pequeno Almoço">
</div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-info">Pequeno Almoço</button>
</form>
```

php:

```
$codigo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["codigo"]); 
$PequenoAlmoco = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["tarefa"]);    

$sql = "INSERT INTO teste (`codigo`, `tarefa`)
VALUES ('$codigo', '$PequenoAlmoco')";

$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql);
```

Assim funciona corretamente, mas se acrescentar o botão para guardar a data e hora do inicio da tarefa ao clicar no botão, já não insere ao clicar no botão da tarefa.

código:

```js
function formatDate(date) {
var monthNames = [
"Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março",
"Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho",
"Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro",
"Novembro", "Dezembro"
  ];

  var day = date.getDate();
  var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var min = date.getMinutes();
  var sec = date.getSeconds();

  return year + '-' + (monthIndex+1) + '-' + day + ' ' + hours + ':' + min + ':' + sec;
}


var dtTime;
$('#IniciarTarefa').on('click', function () {
   $(this).closest('.form-group').data('inicio', formatDate( new Date() ) );
});

$("#form").submit(function(e){ 
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "./conexaoteste",
     data: $("#form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (data)
       {   
    }, 
     error: function(data){
    $(".error_message").removeClass('hide'); // error message
     },
     
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" id="form"> 
<input type="hidden" id="codigo" name="codigo" value="<?= $_GET['codigo'] ?>" /> 
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="IniciarTarefa" id="acao"></label>
<div class="col-md-4">
<button id="IniciarTarefa" name="IniciarTarefa" class="btn btn-info">Iniciar Tarefa</button>
</div>
</div>  
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="PequenoAlmoco" id="acao"></label>
<div class="col-md-4">
<input type="hidden" id="PequenoAlmoco" name="tarefa" value="Pequeno Almoço">
</div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-info">Pequeno Almoço</button>
</form>
```

php:

```
$codigo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["codigo"]); 
$IniciarTarefa = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["IniciarTarefa"]);
$PequenoAlmoco = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["tarefa"]);    

$sql = "INSERT INTO teste (`codigo`, `IniciarTarefa`, `tarefa`)
VALUES ('$codigo', '$IniciarTarefa', '$PequenoAlmoco')";

$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql);
```

A ideia é, clicar no botão Iniciar Tarefa, e guardar a data e hora no value do botão ou numa variável e depois ao clicar no botão com o nome da tarefa (pequeno almoço) inserir o código do primeiro input, a data e a hora em que dei inicio à tarefa e o nome da tarefa.

Comment: Importante você [edit] seu post e explicar detalhadamente o problema, descrevendo o que tentou e onde está a dificuldade atual. Pedidos de refatoração, código pronto, análise de códigos complexos que envolvem mais de uma funcionalidade no mesmo post geralmente não se encaixam no [escopo do site](/help/on-topic). Links para entender melhor o funcionamento do SOpt: [Tour], [Ask], [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/70) e [Help]. Se tem dúvida em algum detalhe específico, reduza o código a um [MCVE] com o problema atual e poste somente a parte relevante.

Answer (score 1):

não entendi exatamente, mais vou tentar responder

clica no seu banco de dados depois vai em sql
coloca esse comando:
`ALTER TABLE SUA_TABELA ADD data datetime;`
^^ ele vai adicionar uma coluna data na sua tabela

`$now = new DateTime();
$datetime = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`
^^ ele vai pegar data, hora, minutos e segundos atual

`$sql = "INSERT INTO teste (codigo, IniciarTarefa, tarefa,data)
VALUES ('$codigo', '$IniciarTarefa', '$PequenoAlmoco','$datetime')";`

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite, não sei se compreendi direito mas você pode armazenar variáveis na `localStorage` com javascript, é melhor que guardar a data e a hora no value do botão como você disse!

```
// Armazenar.
localStorage.setItem("nome", "LUIZ");
// Recuperar.
nomeTela = localStorage.getItem("nome");
//Limpar.
localStorage.clear();
```

Esses dados ficam salvos somente durante a sessão do navegador ou seja quando você fechar os dados se perdem.

Verifique se sua data esta sendo passada corretamente ao MySQL no formato `y-m-d` ou `y/m/d`.

Comment: mas depois como insiro na tabela da base de dados e ao inserir limpo o valor da data?

Comment: Ai você vê como fica melhor, você sta usando Ajax, pode passar por POST ao PHP, para deletar o valor do use storage.removeItem(keyName)